# Tap gesture in collection view not able to perform

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uitapgesturerecognizer

Everything works fine until I tap on the image
This is my log--

> 2017-06-14 16:58:09.451 Sliders Menu[3136:252131]
> -[DrinkViewController onButtonTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff025d50cd0   2017-06-14 16:58:09.460 Sliders
> Menu[3136:252131] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DrinkViewController
> onButtonTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
> 0x7ff025d50cd0

this is my custom cell.m file(colcell.m)

## import "ColCell.h"

```
@implementation ColCell
-(void)awakeFromNib {
UITapGestureRecognizer * tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonTapped:)];
[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[self addGestureRecognizer:tap];

[super awakeFromNib];
}



-(void)onButtonTapped:(id)sender
{


//the response to the gesture.
//mind that this is done in the cell. If you don't want things to happen from this cell.
//then you can still activate this the way you did in your question.

}
```

This is my collection view method

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{


ColCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


if(self.iname!=0){
    
    [cell setTag:indexPath.row];    // set tag to the indexPath.row so we can access it later
    
    // add interactivity
    UITapGestureRecognizer * tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonTapped:)];
    
    [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.iname]; //objectAtIndex:indexPath];
    
    NSLog(@"%@",fileName);
    
    NSString *baseurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.kre8tives.com/barebon/upload/"];
    
    NSDictionary *dict = self.iname[indexPath.row];
    
    NSLog(@"%@", [self.iname objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]);
    
    NSString *paths = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", baseurl, dict];
    
    NSLog(@"@@@@%@",paths);
    
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:paths]] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        
        NSLog(@"%@",response);
        
        
        UIImage *imgage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        UIImageView *dimg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
        dimg.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [cell.dimg setImage:imgage];
        
        
        if(cell.dimg==!nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Not nil");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"nil");
        }
        if(cell.lbl==!nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Not nil");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"nil");
        }
        
        cell.dimg.image=imgage;
        cell.lbl.text=[self.tempz objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.catid=[self.categoryid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%@",[self.iname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    }];
}
    //if (cell.selected) {
 //   cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // highlight selection
  // }
 // else
  // {
    // cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // Default color
  // }
   return cell;
 }

 -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UICollectionViewCell *datasetCell =[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
datasetCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // Default color
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"d2" sender:self];
}
```

my aim is to perform segue the image is tapped and send a data through segue but my problem is that if I tap on the image I get an error and I have all the connections and everything working gr8!!

Comment: change your gesture target

Comment: Where is declared `onButtonTapped:`?

Comment: no need of thi gesture `-(void)awakeFromNib {
UITapGestureRecognizer * tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonTapped:)];
[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[self addGestureRecognizer:tap];

[super awakeFromNib];
}`

Comment: I was trying to perform segue in colcell file it didn't work!!! thanks for the help guys!!!

Comment: @Akshay - see the collectionview delegate once you called the wrong method

Comment: can I use the same colcell file for next view controller too?i.e customcell file??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   UIImageView *dimg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
    dimg.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [cell.dimg setImage:imgage];
    [cell.dimg  setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
 [cell.dimg setTag:indexPath.row];    // set tag to the indexPath.row so we can access it later

// add interactivity
UITapGestureRecognizer * tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonTapped:)];

[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

[cell.dimg addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

and handle the action like

```
- (void)onButtonTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
 //UIImageView *myImage = (UIImageView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
 // do stuff;
NSLog(@"it works");
}
```

**check the collectionview delegate**

it is not in **didDeselectItemAtIndexPath**

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

it is in **didselectItemAtIndexPath**

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like onButtonTapped method not found in your class, thats why its giving you the crash.

Answer (score 1):

Its because the function is in collection cell

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:cell action:@selector(onButtonTapped:)];
```

Comment: so can I remove the whole method in colcell.m file??

Comment: Yeah. You can add the function in viewController if you are using target `self` in viewcontroller